# Libgdx - Android - My coordinates have not the origin in the very bottom

Tags: java, android, libgdx, coordinates, axis

I have a 480x800 resolution and I'm using the following code to set it:

`cam = new OrthographicCamera();
 cam.setToOrtho(false, VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT);
 viewport = new FitViewport(VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT, cam);`

nothing strange further in my code but my issue is that the origin point (0,0) is not on the very bottom but something like 20 pixels upper.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tenfour04 should be right here, but i try to explain it a bit:
The `FitViewport` is there to guarantee, that the virtual aspect ratio (VIRTUAL_HEIGHT/VIRTUAL_WIDTH) is the same as the aspect ratio on screen. Therefore, if your "real" aspect ratio (of the screen) is different, then the virtual one, black borders are shown, to create a "window" which matches the virtual aspect ratio.
Therefore the P(0/0) is not the bottom left corner of the screen, but the bottom left corner of the new "window".
If thats not what you want, there are other `Viewport`s, which may fit your needs.
The `StretchViewport` for example supports virtual screen sizes and simply stretches the image to fit the screens real aspect ratio. This could be better in your case, but in some other cases the stretched images just don't look good...

Answer (score 0):

FitViewport does not guarantee that 0,0 will be in the corner when you center it. All other existing Viewport subclasses do, so use one of those. And make sure you are calling `update` on the viewport in the `resize` method of you Game or Screen subclass.

Edit:
Actually, FillViewport also doesn't guarantee 0,0 in the corner, because 0,0 could be cropped off.

Comment: I think you mean to call viewport.update() from the ApplicationListener / Screen resize() method?

Comment: I'm using FitViewport because I thought that calling its .uptade () method in my resize() I'd have been able to have my camera with every screen resolution. Am I wrong? Which one should I use?

Comment: @GiuseppeTrapasso It depends on what you want to have happen. FitViewport makes sure that the rectangle defined by `VIRTUAL_WIDTH, VIRTUAL_HEIGHT` will completely fit in the screen, so some of the screen will be unused if your aspect ratio doesn't match the screen, and therefore 0,0 won't be in the corner of the screen. In my opinion, ExtendViewport is the right choice for probably 90% of 2D games for mobile. FitViewport may make sense for a cutscene or for GUI only.

Comment: And for the other 10% of games a custom Viewport subclass would be the solution. StretchViewport causes distortion. FillViewport crops off stuff so you'd have to constantly be concerned with where you place objects that need to be seen. And FitViewport uses black bars, so users will be annoyed that you're wasting screen real estate.